# For an orthogonal matrix $W$ and diagonal matrix $T$, why is $\mathrm{trace}(W^{\mathsf{T}} T W) = \mathrm{trace}(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an orthogonal matrix $W$ and a diagonal matrix $T$, both with dimensions $n \times n$, why is the following true ? Can someone write out the proof explicitly please ?

$$\mathrm{trace}(W^{\mathsf{T}} T W) = \mathrm{trace}(T)$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are Allowed to use $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ there is a nice proof.
As $$\operatorname{tr}(W^T TW)=\operatorname{tr}(W^T (TW))=\operatorname{tr}((TW) W^{-1})=\operatorname{tr}(T (WW^{-1}))=\operatorname{tr}(T)$$

Answer (score 4):

The trace is invariant under cyclic permutations of the argument (eg, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29#Basic_properties)).

Since $W$ is orthogonal, you have $W W^T = I$. Hence
$\operatorname{tr}(W^T T W ) = \operatorname{tr}(W W^T T) = \operatorname{tr}(T ) $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Trace is invariant under cyclic permutations, i.e. for any $n\times n$ matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$, 
$$\mathrm{tr}(ABC)=\mathrm{tr}(BCA)=\mathrm{tr}(CAB).$$
Also, by definition, a matrix $W$ is orthogonal precisely when $W^{\mathsf{T}}=W^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic polynomials are fixed under conjugation, and the trace is one of the coefficients.